# RSA/ECB/PKCSPadding1 encryption with .NET from public key bytes

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa, x509

I'd like C# code to encrypt a small string (password) using the RSA/ECB/PKCSPadding1 cipher and the bytes of the public key. The test for the encryption is to decrypt the encrypted value with Java code (which has explicit support for this cipher) using the private key. The java code looks like this:

```
static String decrypt(String encryptedB64, String privateKeyBase64)
{
    try {
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyBase64);
        Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

        KeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

        rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        return new String(rsa.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedB64)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem or question? You don't state a problem, and you don't ask a question.

Comment: I'd like code to encrypt = how do I encrypt

Answer (score 2):

Later versions of dotnet platform support PKCS1 padding explicitly. This code works for me. I encrypt with C# and confirm that I can decrypt using Java with RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding cipher. The only catch is that I have to know in advance how many bits are in the public key (e.g. 1024, 2048).

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String pubB64 = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCK8xP3JO4exQPIB2eDpAVXasM3YOoZN405HuaSjr1FVE0Z++jKrVhTiOYqiXX7ksChmoEt4uim+tWK/1SNpMyD/nl4SsQjkG0zRJr+kfP4owDnQdZRDPpLZABI2X5O6o5bgwPsxY3UfuenwrKc1/FQRITfaTp7nyoX956EZ9v4dQIDAQAB";
        String text = "abcdefg123456";
        byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pubB64);

        var keyLengthBits = 1024;  // need to know length of public key in advance!
        byte[] exponent = new byte[3];
        byte[] modulus = new byte[keyLengthBits / 8];
        Array.Copy(publicKeyBytes, publicKeyBytes.Length - exponent.Length, exponent, 0, exponent.Length);
        Array.Copy(publicKeyBytes, publicKeyBytes.Length - exponent.Length - 2 - modulus.Length, modulus, 0, modulus.Length);

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSAParameters rsaKeyInfo = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
        rsaKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
        rsaKeyInfo.Exponent = exponent;
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo);

        byte[] encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(textBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));

    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be more about your particular ad-hoc method for serializing/deserializing an RSA modulus than it is about PKCS1 padding.

Comment: fair comment, perhaps the title should reflect that. It took far too long to discover both the RSA modulus technique and the magic parameter to pass to Encrypt. There is a lot of junk out there on the internet perhaps due to obsolete apis. Both tricks were important.

Comment: This helped me solve a similar problem I was having!  Thanks man!